# Проблема с двумерный массивами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан целочисленный двумерный массив, размерности n х m. Найти сумму и произведение элементов, кратных 3 и 5

не знаю с чего начать, помогите

Comment: numpy, sympy etc.

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/numpy/2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def sum_product_3_5(arr):
    product = 1
    sum = 0
    for sub_arr in arr:
        # sub_arr - это подмассивы [1, 2, 3] и [3, 4, 5]
        for el in sub_arr:
            # el - это элемент в подмассиве  - 1
            if el % 3 == 0 or el % 5 == 0:
                sum += el
                product *= el
    return product, sum
```

Example:

```
arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
sum_product_3_5(arr)
```

Вернет кортеж: (90, 14)

Comment: что нужно указывать в параметре (arr) ?

Comment: при вызове функции

Comment: твой двумерный массив:

Comment: можно какой-нибудь пример ?

Comment: что значит sub_arr и el ??

Comment: @Jevgewa - смотри выше